# Best way to pass url as parameter to route

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass any full url in as parameter to route, but the slash seems to mess everything up. If a route is passed in encoded, the route seems to decode it, is there a way to stop this or encode the url again at route level?

```
Route::get('add/{title?}/{url?}', 'HomeController@add')->name('add');
```

also i have tired

```
Route::get('add/{title?}/{url?}', 'HomeController@add_')->where('url', '(.*)')->name('add_popup');
```

but if it comes across question mark in the url it will drop anything after the question mark.

Comment: how about replacing the slashes before sending the url and then replace them back?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out

```
Route::get("url/{url}", function($url) {
    return $url;
})->where('url', '.*');
```

Example: http://myapp.test/url/http://try.me.com prints

> http://try.me.com

Comment: This is working with your scenario but some URLs with params it's not working. Like: http://devrolabs.com/?ref=formsubmit.co

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Jeunes answer, however if you still want a route parameter you could do a base64 encode/decode. This will not make for a pretty url though.

JS

```
btoa("http://someurl.test")
```

PHP

```
Route::get('url/{url}', function ($url) {
    return base64_decode($url);
});
```

Comment: Ok you need to manually be able to paste an url to the browsers address bar without any script proxy?